# insert a multi-dimensional array to mysql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to insert this multidemensional array from a dynamic jquery form but im not sure how to tackle this. The array shows as the following when printed:

```
[item] => Array ( 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [unit] => service 
        [qty] => 3 
        [description] => Description 1 
        [price] => $ 33 
        [tax] => 60 % 
        [total] => $ 158.40
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [unit] => hours 
        [qty] => 74 
        [description] => Description 2 
        [tax] => 3 % 
        [total] => $ 3,429.90 ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [unit] => days 
        [qty] => 67 
        [description] => Description 3 
        [tax] => 6 % 
        [total] => $ 284.08 ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
        [unit] => product 
        [qty] => 72 
        [description] => Description 4 
        [tax] => 34 % 
        [total] => $ 3,183.84 
    ) 
)
```

I used this as my for each statement but it didnt work:

```
$returnedData = $_POST['item'];

      foreach($returnedData as $data) {
                $unit = $data['unit'];
                $qty = $data['qty'];
                $description = $data['description'];
                $tax = $data['tax'];
                $price = $data['price'];
                $subtotal = $data['total'];
      }

    $insert_items = mysqli_query($connect_db,"INSERT INTO items (invoice_id, date, unit, qty, description, tax, price, subtotal) VALUES ($invoice, $todays_date, $unit, $qty, $description, $tax, $price, $subtotal)");
```

Anyone know how to capture all of the data? Is it a for each loop?

Comment: instead of $unit = $data['unit']; use $unit = $data->unit;

Comment: @PankajSharma It's an array value, accessing it like a object (`->`) won't work.

Comment: @jack I placed it inside and it still doesn't work.

Comment: *Warning*: there is a sql injection opportunity available to your snippet.

Comment: I bet the result of `mysqli_query()` is `false` because you have an error in the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be this will help you. as this is a multidimensional array you can apply one more loop to get the value and write INSERT query after the first loop

```
$returnedData = $_POST['item'];

foreach($returnedData as $value=>$data) 
{
        $unit = $data['unit'];
        $qty = $data['qty'];
        $description = $data['description'];
        $tax = $data['tax'];
        $price = $data['price'];
        $subtotal = $data['total'];

    $insert_items = mysqli_query($connect_db,"INSERT INTO items 
    (invoice_id, date, unit, qty, description, tax, price, subtotal) 
    VALUES 
    ($invoice, $todays_date, $unit, $qty, $description, $tax, $price, $subtotal)");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? It'll generate errors due to the second foreach loop looking for array keys but intact, what you've done is turn a multi-yeardimensional array into strings contained in $data

Comment: @DarylGill just tried it and youre right, strings show up instead of the actual post.

Comment: @DarylGill also, if you try and input two dynamic inputs, it has a mysql error and only insert one row (the first item)

Comment: @lancey Remove the second foreach loop  and change the `$data` variable to ` $unit = $value['unit'];`

Comment: @DarylGill Thanks so much for helping.... It now properly shows the first input as a row in MYSQL but errors out for each additional row.

Comment: @DarylGill Thanks ... I've tried to update the code.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava Thanks for the help... Same error occurs, it properly inputs the first array but errors out for each addition array

Comment: Is it the `$invoice` which might is causing the issue as it probably is a primary key. Or do tell your error message.

Comment: Thanks @lancey its pleasure helping you .. if possible please take your downvote back.

Comment: im sorry @MohitShrivastava it doesnt allow me to up vote or down vote.

Comment: The down vote was not me. Simple code changes to rectify a solution do not make me downvote. I'll +1 to even it out, as a downvote is not necessary now

Comment: Thanks @DarylGill. You made a nice start to my day :)